# Is it possible to load a redis module (redisbloom) onto a redis helm chart (bitnami/redis or bitnami/redis-cluster)?

Tags: kubernetes, redis, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to add the redisbloom module to a redis helm chart (bitnami/redis), or ideally the redis cluster chart (bitnami/redis-cluster).

```
# Chart.yaml

apiVersion: v2
name: my-app
description: My app and redis (with redisbloom module loaded)
type: application
version: 0.1.0
appVersion: 0.1.0
dependencies:
  - name: redis
    alias: redisbloom
    version: 12.1.1
    repository: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
```

Copying the compiled module `redisbloom.so` to each pod, and then loading the module either post-start or with `master.command=redis-server --load-module=<path>/redisbloom.so` seemed like it could be a potential solution - however from the documentation I can't see how to copy the binary across for a chart.

I'm also not sure this would be enough on it's own for a master-slave or cluster situation to work. This [Github issue](https://github.com/RedisBloom/RedisBloom/issues/29) suggests it should be possible to do - but alas there is no documentation that I can find to support it.

Is it possible? Or would I need to create a custom chart, for example, using the RedisBloom docker image [redislabs/rebloom]?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From where you want to copy the file? Maybe you can create a initContainer with the desired commands to copy the file and load the module, but if it is really necessary I'll go to a custom docker image. What do you think?

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to build custom redis image based on bitnami image with required module and after that use extraVars var to specify your module like: --loadmodule /usr/lib/redis/modules/redisearch.so

My Dockerfile for that (I need to have redisearch module):

```
#### My customization
FROM redislabs/redisearch:latest AS moduleimg
#### End of
FROM docker.io/bitnami/minideb:buster
LABEL maintainer "Bitnami <containers@bitnami.com>"

ENV HOME="/" \
    OS_ARCH="amd64" \
    OS_FLAVOUR="debian-10" \
    OS_NAME="linux"

COPY prebuildfs /
# Install required system packages and dependencies
RUN install_packages acl ca-certificates curl gzip libc6 libssl1.1 procps tar wget
RUN . /opt/bitnami/scripts/libcomponent.sh && component_unpack "wait-for-port" "1.0.0-3" --checksum 7521d9a4f9e4e182bf32977e234026caa7b03759799868335bccb1edd8f8fd12
RUN . /opt/bitnami/scripts/libcomponent.sh && component_unpack "redis" "6.2.1-0" --checksum c104089841a906f944e285828a580968608017340b67befaa1771646cbfdf6b3
RUN . /opt/bitnami/scripts/libcomponent.sh && component_unpack "gosu" "1.12.0-2" --checksum 4d858ac600c38af8de454c27b7f65c0074ec3069880cb16d259a6e40a46bbc50
RUN chmod g+rwX /opt/bitnami
RUN ln -s /opt/bitnami/scripts/redis/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN ln -s /opt/bitnami/scripts/redis/run.sh /run.sh

COPY rootfs /
RUN /opt/bitnami/scripts/redis/postunpack.sh
ENV BITNAMI_APP_NAME="redis" \
    BITNAMI_IMAGE_VERSION="6.2.1-debian-10-r14" \
    PATH="/opt/bitnami/common/bin:/opt/bitnami/redis/bin:$PATH"

### My customization
RUN mkdir /opt/bitnami/redis/modules
COPY --from=moduleimg /usr/lib/redis/modules/redisearch.so* /opt/bitnami/redis/modules
### End of

EXPOSE 6379

USER 1001
ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/bitnami/scripts/redis/entrypoint.sh" ]
CMD [ "/opt/bitnami/scripts/redis/run.sh" ]
```

Comment: I couldn't find the 'extraVars' you suggested. But the recommended way is to use config `commonConfiguration` and adding `loadmodule /opt/bitnami/redis/modules/redisearch.so` to the config.

Comment: Can you explain this a little more? How did you get the main docker file?

Comment: I'm almost always use bitnami images for helm. So if you want to find Dockerfile source for some image you need to google something like: "bitnami redis github" and after few clicks on links: https://github.com/bitnami/containers/blob/main/bitnami/redis/6.2/debian-11/Dockerfile

Answer (score 2):

I would use a custom image, for example:

```
FROM redislabs/rebloom:latest as builder

FROM bitnami/redis:6.2.10
COPY --from=builder /usr/lib/redis/modules/redisbloom.so /usr/lib/redis/modules/redisbloom.so

CMD ["/run.sh", "--loadmodule", "/usr/lib/redis/modules/redisbloom.so"]
```

Comment: does this work?

Answer (score 0):

In my idea you must to build custom redis image based on bitnami redis image with required module and after that, you must add some config on helm chart configs for load custom module, this is complete example for redisearch:

```
# Copyright VMware, Inc.
# SPDX-License-Identifier: APACHE-2.0
FROM redislabs/redisearch:latest AS searchmoduleimg


FROM docker.io/bitnami/minideb:bullseye

ARG TARGETARCH

LABEL com.vmware.cp.artifact.flavor="sha256:1e1b4657a77f0d47e9220f0c37b9bf7802581b93214fff7d1bd2364c8bf22e8e" \
      org.opencontainers.image.base.name="docker.io/bitnami/minideb:bullseye" \
      org.opencontainers.image.created="2023-11-09T18:25:18Z" \
      org.opencontainers.image.description="Application packaged by VMware, Inc" \
      org.opencontainers.image.licenses="Apache-2.0" \
      org.opencontainers.image.ref.name="7.2.3-debian-11-r1" \
      org.opencontainers.image.title="redis" \
      org.opencontainers.image.vendor="VMware, Inc." \
      org.opencontainers.image.version="7.2.3"

ENV HOME="/" \
    OS_ARCH="${TARGETARCH:-amd64}" \
    OS_FLAVOUR="debian-11" \
    OS_NAME="linux"

COPY prebuildfs /
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-o", "pipefail", "-c"]
# Install required system packages and dependencies
RUN install_packages ca-certificates curl libgomp1 libssl1.1 procps
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/bitnami/pkg/cache/ && cd /tmp/bitnami/pkg/cache/ && \
    COMPONENTS=( \
      "wait-for-port-1.0.7-3-linux-${OS_ARCH}-debian-11" \
      "redis-7.2.3-1-linux-${OS_ARCH}-debian-11" \
    ) && \
    for COMPONENT in "${COMPONENTS[@]}"; do \
      if [ ! -f "${COMPONENT}.tar.gz" ]; then \
        curl -SsLf "https://downloads.bitnami.com/files/stacksmith/${COMPONENT}.tar.gz" -O ; \
        curl -SsLf "https://downloads.bitnami.com/files/stacksmith/${COMPONENT}.tar.gz.sha256" -O ; \
      fi && \
      sha256sum -c "${COMPONENT}.tar.gz.sha256" && \
      tar -zxf "${COMPONENT}.tar.gz" -C /opt/bitnami --strip-components=2 --no-same-owner --wildcards '*/files' && \
      rm -rf "${COMPONENT}".tar.gz{,.sha256} ; \
    done
RUN apt-get autoremove --purge -y curl && \
    apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists /var/cache/apt/archives
RUN chmod g+rwX /opt/bitnami
RUN ln -s /opt/bitnami/scripts/redis/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN ln -s /opt/bitnami/scripts/redis/run.sh /run.sh

COPY rootfs /
RUN /opt/bitnami/scripts/redis/postunpack.sh
ENV APP_VERSION="7.2.3" \
    BITNAMI_APP_NAME="redis" \
    PATH="/opt/bitnami/common/bin:/opt/bitnami/redis/bin:$PATH"

### My customization
RUN mkdir /opt/bitnami/redis/modules
COPY --from=searchmoduleimg /usr/lib/redis/modules/redisearch.so* /opt/bitnami/redis/modules

### End of

EXPOSE 6379

USER 1001
ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/bitnami/scripts/redis/entrypoint.sh" ]
CMD [ "/opt/bitnami/scripts/redis/run.sh"]
```

After build your iamge, add these lines to start-master.sh and start-replica.sh in script-config.yaml:

```
exec redis-server \
--loadmodule /opt/bitnami/redis/modules/redisearch.so MAXSEARCHRESULTS 10000 MAXAGGREGATERESULTS 10000 \
"${ARGS[@]}"
{{- end }}
```

now you can use custom mosule.